# How to group same kind of values into common one and group by that

Tags: mysql, group-by

Hi I was looking for a mysql query result like [image]

As you can see there are some values have the kind of values (Ex: BV and BR or C5 and C7) how can I combine then together into one common value lets say B or C and group by that in sql?
I have the following query:

```
SELECT  

type,
 sum(case when status ='valid' then 1 else 0 end) valid_jobs,
 sum(case when status ='non-valid' then 1 else 0 end) non_valid_jobs,
 sum(case when status IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) null_jobs

 from 

main_table  

where  

SUBSTRING_INDEX(CAST(CAST(from_unixtime(date_generated) AS DATE) AS CHAR), '-',2)  REGEXP '^2016' 

group by type
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Otcome will look like:
[image]

Comment: post the desired outcome !

Comment: updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an expression that evaluates the value of the `type` column, and returns the desired result.

What's not clear from the question is the "mapping" from `type` to the value you want returned in the first column. It looks like we might be looking at just the first character of value in the `type` column.

```
SUBSTR(type,1,1)
```

If the "mapping" is more involved, then we could use a CASE expression. For example:

```
CASE 
  WHEN type IN ('BV','BR','BT','ZB') THEN 'B'
  WHEN type IN ('C5','C7')           THEN 'C'
  WHEN ...                           THEN ...
  ELSE type
END
```

We'd use that as the first expression in the SELECT list (replacing the reference to the `type` column in the original query), and in the GROUP BY clause.

---

On an (unrelated) performance note, we'd prefer conditions in the WHERE clause to be on *bare columns*. That allows MySQL to make use of an (efficient) range scan operation on an appropriate index.

With this condition:

```
  WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(CAST(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.date_generated ) AS DATE) AS CHAR), '-',2) 
        REGEXP '^2016'
```

We're forcing MySQL to evaluate the expression on the left side for *every* row in the table. And the value returned by the expression is compared.

If what we're really trying to do is get `date_generated` values in 2016, assuming that `date_generated` is INTEGER type, storing 32-bit unix-style number of seconds since beginning of the era 1970-01-01...

We can do something like this:

```
  WHERE t.date_generated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01') 
    AND t.date_generated <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01')
```

MySQL will see that as a range operation on the values in te `date_generated` column. And with that, MySQL can make effective use of an index that has `date_generated` as a leading column.

---

Just replace `expr` with the expression that returns the values you want in the first column:

```
 SELECT expr
      , SUM(IF( t.status = 'valid'     ,1,0)) AS valid_jobs
      , SUM(IF( t.status = 'non-valid' ,1,0)) AS non_valid_jobs
      , SUM(IF( t.status IS NULL       ,1,0)) AS null_jobs
   FROM main_table t  
  WHERE t.date_generated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01') 
    AND t.date_generated <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') 
  GROUP BY expr
```

**EDIT**

To guarantee that rows are returned in a particular sequence, add an ORDER BY clause, e.g.

```
  ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    SELECT  
            LEFT(type,1) AS type,
            sum(case when status ='valid' then 1 else 0 end) valid_jobs,
            sum(case when status ='non-valid' then 1 else 0 end) non_valid_jobs,
            sum(case when status IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) null_jobs
    FROM 
            main_table  
    WHERE  
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(CAST(CAST(from_unixtime(date_generated) AS DATE) AS CHAR), '-',2)  REGEXP '^2016' 

    GROUP BY 
            type
```